# Sikuli IDE can't import other script JRuby

Tags: jruby, sikuli

I'm working with SikuliIDE 1.1.0

Script1:

```
#script 1
require 'java'

popup("hello, I am script1")
import 'script2'
reload(script2)
from script2 import *
myPop() # call function myPop in script2
```

script 2

```
# content of script2.sikuli
from sikuli import *
popup("hello I'm script2")
```

When I run script 1 I get the next error:

[error] NameError ( (NameError) cannot load Java class script2 )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first line: class ( method ) file 1286: org.jruby.javasupport.JavaClass ( for_name ) org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java 34: org.jruby.javasupport.JavaUtilities ( get_proxy_class ) org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java 27: RUBY ( java_import ) file:/D:/Sikuli/sikulix.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb 2412: org.jruby.RubyArray ( map ) org/jruby/RubyArray.java 22: RUBY ( java_import ) file:/D:/Sikuli/sikulix.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb 5: RUBY ( (root) ) D:/sikuli scripts.sikuli [error] --- Traceback --- end --------------

Both scripts are stored in the same folder. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

okay, got it working with the change using "require 'd:\script2.sikuli\script2.rb'" i.s.o. the import. 
But, it should also be working with an import somehow...